# Entity Framework - seeding database - does PK need to be included in Seed method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, seeding

Following the [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4) tutorial, the database is seeded with sample data. The `Album` class is as follows:

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int      AlbumId     { get; set;}
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then in the sample data class that's used in the tutorial, an `Album` object is created like this within the `Seed()` method:

```
new Album { Title = "The Best Of Billy Cobham", 
Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Jazz"), 
Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Billy Cobham"), 
AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" }
```

In **my** project I have a class `Tenant`:

```
public class Tenant
{
    [key]
    public int      TenantId     { get; set;}
    // ...
}
```

In my `Seed()` method, I create a Tenant like this:

```
new Tenant { UserId=1,  UserName="Matthew" /*...*/ }
```

In my `Seed()` method I've included the Tenant PK which is UserId - Tenant is derived from User. I'm wondering, because in the Seed() method I've explicitly said that the Tenant's PK of UserId is 1, will that cause a problem when the method run? I ask because in the music store tutorial, the author hasn't included an Album's PK.

So the PK isn't explicitly stated when creating an Album. Will EF apply a PK by default? I've just spent a while creating quite a lot of sample data for my own project, and I've put the PK for a lot of entities in manually - will EF accept this or will it cause me problems? Is seeding the best way to generate sample data - alternatives?

Comment: EF will create an appropriate PK everytime you add and save the changes to the db afaik. The added model won't reflect the PK until after SaveChanges is called

Comment: No all classes that are mapped to a table have their PK annotated with `[key]` and are of type `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't add a `[Key]` attribute, EF will try to find an int readable - writeable property named `Id` or `<yourClassName>Id`.

That's all. And That's why AlbumId is taken as PK for class Album : No key attribute exists in that class, AlbumId = `<nameOfClass>Id`, it's a readable-writeable int.

If you have set a Key attribute, EF won't try to find another one. It's just a convention, which allow you to be less verbose.

For sample datas, `Seed()` method's body is a fine way to put them in Code First.

Comment: Just saw your edit, so setting the key attribute in the Seed() method won't be an issue?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, was supposed to be on TenantId...!

Comment: But if Tenant inherits from User, and User has alread an UserId PK, you don't need anohter PK in Tenant...

Comment: But in my Seed() method I'm not creating User entities, I'm only creating entities that derive from User, which are Tenant and Landlord. Am I not right to assign a PK then?

Comment: I think you shouldn't, indeed. Remove TenantId From Tenant class, and don't set "UserId" in your seed, and you'll be fine (almost certain).

Comment: Okay, you answered my original question anyway so I'll select as answer. Thanks.